# Using listOf vs arrayListOf

Tags: kotlin

Is there any best practice as for using `listOf()` or `arrayListOf()` in Kotlin code?
They both actually returns the same implementation and I understand listOf is better in the sense that it is not tied to specific implementation. 
[Here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/index.html) are the docs for it?
Is it documented anywhere in the language style?
Are there any other reasons to use each one?

Comment: more interesting is probably the difference between `mutableListOf` and `arrayListOf`... but s1m0nw1's answer can be applied to that as well (bottom part of the answer)....

Comment: yes, I just missed the fact that it is mutable.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One notable and important difference is that `listOf` gives you a *read-only* `List` whereas `arrayListOf` gives you a `MutableList`. It's definitely preferred to use read-only data structures whenever possible.

```
val l1 = listOf(1)
l1.add(2) //not possible

val l2 = arrayListOf(2)
l2.add(1) //ok
```

On the other hand, if you don't fully rely on type inference, you can make the variable for the ArrayList read-only as well:

```
val l3: List<Int> = arrayListOf(2)
l3.add(1) //not possible anymore
```

The point of not using `arrayListOf` is that you want to rely on the library to choose the actual implementation. As of now this happens to be an `ArrayList` which could change in future releases. For instance, if Kotlin decides to add a more powerful backward-compatible version of an ArrayList, they could change the implementation and your code would keep working (in an improved way). If you, on the other hand, want to rely on ArrayList (via `arrayListOf`), you probably have a concrete scenario were only this implementation is acceptable.

Comment: One exception to using read-only whenever possible is if you have a long list that you want to modify, especially on the UI thread. Read-only lists have to be copied into a new lists each time you want to modify them, and this can cause stuttering during UI animation if the size of the list is significant.